# Android, OrmLite - Observe external changes of dao

Tags: android, ormlite, observable

How can I observe changes if they are made externally, e.g. in a service or via a broadcast receiver?

I listen like this:

```
myDao.registerObserver(this);
```

And when the db changes in service or in a broadcast receiver, the method `void onChange()` does not get called.

I am using OrmLite v5.0

Answer (score 1):

> How can I observe changes if they are made externally, e.g. in a service or via a broadcast receiver?

The ORMLite observer only works when monitoring calls to the same `myDao` instance.  There is no way for ORMLite to somehow intercept database calls via other mechanisms to report on them.  Is that really what you are asking?

You could do periodic queries to your database to detect new rows or changes to existing rows but that seems expensive.  You can certainly configure your entities to update a `lastModified` field with the current time to make it easier.

An additional solution might be some sort of database proxy.  Other solutions would be for the other database updates send some sort of out-of-band notification when rows are updated.

Hope this helps.